# curl do not work if it is executed from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, curl

I am stuck with this issue:

I am trying to run curl using a batch file which is automatically called when password hook is running. The content of this batch file is:

```
curl "http://10.x.y.z/passwd.php?user=%1&pass=%2"
```

User and password are automatically read as you can see below in error log.

But I am still receiving a `curl(27) out of memory ERROR` as you can see below:

```
[Wed Sep 09 12:09:42 2015]
"C:\passwd.bat" testuser Pass@1234

c:\>curl "http://10.x.y.z/passwd.php?user=testuser&pass=Pass@1234"
curl: (27) Out of memory
[Wed Sep 09 12:09:43 2015]
```

If I run the batch file from command prompt with `passwd.bat testuser Pass@1234`, everything is OK.

**Curl and .bat file are running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.**

Do you have any ideas about how could I solve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you try another build/version of curl?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen anyone actually get an out of memory error. Very strange, especially for such a simple use case...

Comment: I have tried but without success. Current version is: 7.39.0-rtmp-ssh2-ssl-sspi-zlib-winidn-static-bin-win64. I have also tried 7.40.0-openssl-libssh2-zlib-x64 and 7.33.0-win64-nossl. I am using WINDOWS SERVER 2012 R2 and php is installed on Redhat 6.4 (where this php script is present)

Comment: Any luck with the current 7.44 from [here](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.44.0) (there are many different builds)?

Comment: Looks like an issue caused by mixed usage of x86 and x64 applications. Is x86 or x64 version of `curl` used? Which command processor (`cmd.exe`) executes the batch file: the 32-bit or the 64-bit version?

Comment: curl version: x64  ;                                                                                                 cmd.exe version: no idea. Is there a way to find out which?

Comment: it seems that curl-7.21.7-win64-ssl-sspi works well, but it needs Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable package. I still want to use a newer version of Curl. I have tried with 43, 44 but without success.